# Student claims $\lim_{x \to 0^+} \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$. Is it justified?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, proof-verification, derivatives

I am a tutor of an introductory calculus course in our college of engineering. The students are first year engineering undergraduates. We had a quiz where the following question was asked :

> Let $f : [0,1] \to \Bbb R$ be continuous on $[0,1]$ and differentiable on $(0,1)$. If $\lim_{x \to 0^+} f'(x)=L$ for some real number $L$, then show that $f'(0)$ exists and $f'(0)=L$

The students had been taught Lagrange's mean value theorem prior to that. So it was expected that they will use it. However, some students have written the following answer:

> $L=\lim_{x \to 0^+} f'(x)= \lim_{x \to 0^+}  \lim_{h \to 0} \frac {f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac {f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac {f(h)-f(0)}{h}.$
>
> This implies that $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac {f(h)-f(0)}{h}$ exists hence $f'(0)$ exists and equals $L$.

In this, they have not provided any justification for exchanging the limits. I am not able to find any justification for that step nor I am able to counter it. Can someone throw some light on this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second "$=$" in the students' answers is an invalid assumption. Interchanging the order (e.g of $h$ and $x$ ) in the limits often fails to preserve values. To justify a change of order requires additional work.

Suppose we were not given that $\lim_{x\to 0}f'(x)$ exists. Read the students' answer in reverse order. The reversal of the order of limits would then seem to imply that $f'$ is continuous at $0$ merely from $f$ being differentiable, which is a false conclusion.

So ask them: How & where did you use the existence of $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f'(x)$ to justify the reversal?  The correct answer is "Nowhere".

Comment: This is the best answer to this question, in my opinion. +1

Answer (score 4):

Blindly interchanging the limits without any justifications cannot not be accepted as a valid answer. Here is a valid proof: For any $x>0$ there exits $\xi_x \in (0,x)$ such that $\frac {f(x)-f(0)} x =f'(\xi_x)$. If $\epsilon >0$ and $\delta$ is chosen such that $|f'(y)-L| <\epsilon$ for $0 <y <\delta$ then we get $|\frac {f(x)-f(0)} x-L| <\epsilon$ whenever $0 <x <\delta$ and this proves that $f'(0)=L$.

Comment: I agree. That can't be accepted as a valid answer without any reasoning. But can there be a justification for that step? I am confused about that.

Comment: In the present case you can interchange the limits but the justification for that comes only from an $\epsilon -\delta$ argument like the one I have given. There is no simpler justification.

Answer (score 4):

[@glowstonetrees say in their answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3353777/279515)

> Perhaps it's true that
>   $$
> \lim_{x \to 0^+} \lim_{h \to 0} g(x,h) = \lim_{h \to 0} \lim_{x \to 0^+} g(x,h)
> $$
>   if $g(x,h)$ takes the form $g(x,h) = \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$, . . .

I will show that even this need not be the case in general. Let $f \colon [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be the function defined by
$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
0, &x = 0;\\
x^2 \sin(1/x), &x \neq 0.
\end{cases}
$$
Then, on the one hand we have
$$
\lim_{h \to 0^+} \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}
= \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}
=f'(0)
= 0.
$$
On the other hand, we have
$$
\lim_{x \to 0^+} \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} = \lim_{x \to 0^+} f'(x) = \lim_{x \to 0^+} 2x \sin(1/x) - \cos(1/x),
$$
which does not exist.

So, the interchange of the two limits cannot be done simply by knowing that $g(x,h)$ is of the form $\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this truly counts as a counterexample to what you have, but it is a fact that you can't always exchange the order of two limits. Consider for example

$$f(x,y) = \frac{x-y}{x+y}$$

On one hand, we have

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\lim_{y\rightarrow 0} f(x,y) = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac xx = 1$$

But on the other hand,

$$\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} f(x,y) = \lim_{y\rightarrow 0} \frac {-y}{y} = -1$$

so at least it's not true in the general case. Perhaps it's true that

$$\lim_{x \to 0^+}  \lim_{h \to 0} g(x,h) = \lim_{h \to 0} \lim_{x \to 0^+} g(x,h)$$

if $g(x,h)$ takes the form $g(x,h) = \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$, but simply saying that "the order of limits can be exchanged" is certainly not good enough justification.

Comment: A nice example that we can't always interchange limits. But here it seems to be working for them. I am in search of the reasoning for that.

Comment: Yeah, but the thing is, they seem to think that limits can *always* be exchanged (as is evident from how no justification was given for that step). This example shows otherwise. Thus, that step should be considered incorrect, until they explain why the limits can be exchanged in this specific case.

Comment: @Error 404: To further elaborate on glowstonetrees's comment, keep in mind the distinction between the truth of a statement and the justification of a statement. The students just as well may have said: "The year 1900 had 365 days because there are 365 days in a year." (That said, I wonder why something like this rose to the importance of being included on a quiz in a beginning calculus course for engineers *taught in the department of engineering*. I think showing what can go wrong, using specific examples, would be more important than perfecting one's skill at a proof such as this.)